# Is it possible to hardcode a drop down menu in the export .csv file when running a query?

Tags: mysql, excel

What I would like to do is to add a drop down menu in the exported .csv file with hardcoded strings.

For example:

```
SELECT ('pass', 'fail') as decision FROM...
```

The `decision` column is not pulling any data from the DB, it's just created to manually write pass or fail in the decision column in the exported file.
Instead of manually writing pass or fail, I would like the exported `.csv` file to already have the drop down with the 2 options instead of writing them.

I'm not using any programming language, it's just a query.

Is this even possible?

Regards.

Comment: *"Is this even possible?"* Don't think so i don't know a Excel formula that allowes make a dropdown on the "fly" .. Seams there are only functions/formula that are relating to excel data cells.

Answer (score 1):

Every expression in the select-list of a query must be a scalar, not a tuple. You'll get an error if you try the syntax you show above.

```
mysql> SELECT ('pass', 'fail') as decision;
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

It doesn't make any sense to "put a dropdown menu in a .csv file." CSV files are like text, they don't have dropdown menus or any UI controls.

Do you mean you want a text file containing two lines, one for each of the options in your menu?

```
mysql> SELECT 'pass' AS decision 
 UNION SELECT 'fail';
+----------+
| decision |
+----------+
| pass     |
| fail     |
+----------+
```

You don't need to give a column alias for the second or subsequent unioned select statements, because the column header is determined by the first select, and subsequent queries can't change the heading.

Comment: *"It doesn't make any sense to "put a dropdown menu in a .csv file." CSV files are like text, they don't have dropdown menus or any UI controls."* notice the excel tag on the question.. ..

Comment: But notice the mysql tag. Anyway, one can't put UI controls into a csv file exported from _either_ excel or mysql. The UI controls require a richer file format, like `.xslx`.

Comment: I didn't know .csv files have this limitation. I have seen the UNION SELECT method somewhere else but but didn't think it would help my case. The SELECT statement I used was an example since it does not really work in mysql. Thanks.

Comment: *"Anyway, one can't put UI controls into a csv file exported from either excel or mysql. The UI controls require a richer file format, like .xslx"* carefull what you say .cvs importing in excel can do alot including formulas and more ... [CSV Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSV_Injection) is very overlooked  meaning If a UI control in excel is formula controlled it should be possible with a csv file as well .